# Calabash Android script halts

Tags: android, ruby, linux, virtualbox, calabash

When I run the .apk my execution halts for long and script does not executes. I need to explicitly abort it. don't know why it does not executes. there is no error comes on console. do we have any solution to this issue?

What I get the out put while using below commands:

**--> calabash-android resign my-app.apk**  [Done perfect]
**--> calabash-android run my-app.apk** [Initiate for execution and it shows only line **325 KB/s (566732 bytes in 1.700s)** and thereafter it does nothing and **unfortunately every time I need to abort the process.** :-( ]

My phone connection is alive(connected) still it does not execute many times.
for alternative, many times I disconnect the phone and reconnect. I'm using *Nexus4* and *Samsung Galaxy S5* & hope this is not be a phone or cable issue.

For this issue I Google but didn't find exact solution. kindly let me know if there is any solution on this. much appreciated for help.

Comment: Are you sure that your phone is connected to your PC in debug mode? I would recommend you to install genymotion and check is this working.

Comment: Yes my phone is connected to the PC in debug mode.  As you recommending me for genymotion, I'm quite afraid that does it disturb any settings of calabash? also "dkms" is require for genymotion which I don't install till now, hopefully that shouldn't go bad.

Comment: Have you tried doing reinstall_apps? I've seen that work in a few scenarios.

Comment: @Lasse: Yes many times I tried the same.

Comment: @Glorifind : Can I use genymotion in the case of continuous integration. Actually, I got it running using my mobile. Is there any way to operate genymotion by using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox + genymotion should work. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 and it's working fine. Probably it's problem with programmer settings or connection with a phone. Try to reinstall phone drivers or adapter driver(if you are using one)

Comment: Yep, will try that and check. because my scripts executes randomly with my phone.

Comment: it didn't work ? problem might occur also if u have more then 1 virtualdevice or if u have virtualdevice + phone turned on. Then it can just work wrong becouse it can't detect which device should he emulate. On the other hand you might try other telephone becouse it might be a problem with your phone. Last possibility is problem with a calabash script which is not executable

Comment: Till now I haven't used any simulator for my calabash script executions. Secondly I am using real devices at a time and not using as telephone purpose them as well and if thinking about the script then its as simple as shown on the GitHub site with predefined steps and even they are running many of the time, the problem is just inconsistency of executing my scripts.

Comment: Problem is your apk have to be prepared to be tested on real devices thats why i suggested to use emulator, secondly the code must be injected inside a script to handle real devices.
It should help you https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/testing-on-devices/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while working on my project

1> Close your current terminal.

2> Open new terminal and check if your device is connected by typing

```
adb devices
```

It will restart daemon and list devices connected. Make sure your device is connected in USB Debugging mode.

3> After that run your test it should work. :)

Comment: Every time when I connect my phone to PC I first hit the same command and then run my scripts. this would not be the case or reason of loosing the connection. though will try your suggestion once.

Comment: calabash-android run my-app.apk [Initiate for execution and it shows only line 325 KB/s (566732 bytes in 1.700s) ] -> This will uninstall the app and next it will install the app again. I think in your settings you have not given permission for installations. Check your permission manager. This is just a hunch i am not sure if i am correct.

Comment: I'm very newbie to calabash so don't know how to check weather it given permission to install the app or not. Kindly let me know.

Comment: In your mobile go to Settings -> Security,
Under "Device administrators" select "Unknown Sources" toggle switch.
As of now your phone prevents installing aps from unkown sources so it doesnt let u install the apk file. :)

Comment: I am quite sure that your apk is not getting the permission to get installed on your phone. Because after this line :- 325 KB/s (566732 bytes in 1.700s), your phone should ask for permission for installation of the app. I tried not giving permission to my demo app and i got same response like you. It doesn't do anything after the first line.

Comment: Sanoop: As per your advice I have checked the option but its already selected though the same scenario is I'm facing. even now I have change my device to SamSung Galaxy S5, I have checked all above you said but still the situation is as it is.

Comment: How can I manage this issue when I am using the virtual device for continuous integration. It is listing a device and I am getting the error when it starts the installation.